# How To Suppress Apache Error

Tags: apache-2.2

I've gone through the trouble of blocking a number of bots that are trying to crawl our site. The issue now is that the following error is taking over the apache error log:

```
client denied by server configuration
```

I was hoping that an Apache expert out there can tell me how I can suppress the error message for this specific issue from being written to the error log.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -v`

Really.  I mean it.  Why manipulate the logs at time of writing?

**Edit 1**

tail -f -n100 /var/log/httpd/error_log | grep -v 'client denied by server configuration'

If you really want to prevent the error from being written to disk, you can pipe your logs through a script.  More details here:

[Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped)

Comment: @Warner - Fair enough. Any ideas how I can change the following command I currently use to view the log file so that it suppresses those errors? 

tail -100 /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

Comment: @Warner - Thanks! That seems to produce something slightly different since it first grabs 100 lines of the error log and then only shows non-matching lines. Is there a way to instead display the last 100 lines that don't match?

Comment: Try this: `grep -v 'client denied by server configuration' /etc/httpd/logs/error_log | tail -n100`

Comment: > *"Why manipulate the logs at time of writing?"* Because error messages caused by intentional blocking are superfluous and take up disk space. Plenty of programs manipulate logs at the time of writing, like syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng.