# can I suppress apache2 error messages about clients denied by server configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

For about 36 hours I made a config mistake and left an apache2 server forward proxy open to all.
I've closed this, but the server is still getting hammered by hopeful ad spammers. 
My apache error log is filling up with [error] [client 108.62.178.124] client denied by server configuration ...
Can I suppress these error messages?

Comment: Just ride it out. They'll go away in a few days.

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/119353/how-to-suppress-apache-error/119384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the `LogLevel` but you might miss something, that said you could miss something with too much noise!

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#LogLevel

Other potential options:

- If there are only a few IP addresses the firewall them?
- Put the logs into a log analyser and filter the noise, bonus points for setting up alerting on genuine error conditions at this point.

Comment: Thanks, but these are [errors] which means I can't filter them by loglevel, I assume, because errors are always logged. The answer would be to stop this particular error message, but I don't know if it is possible to do that.

Comment: no,I'm wrong. loglevel crit will block them

Comment: It's a scale so `crit`, `alert` and `emerg` won't show `error` (and below).